# PHP email wont send variables

Tags: php, html, email

Basically the following code is an enquiry form that when the website user fills out, it sends the email to my email address. But something isn't working...

Here's the php:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['efName'];
$field_email = $_POST['efEmail'];
$field_phone = $_POST['efPhone'];
$field_date = $_POST['efTravelDate'];
$field_duration = $_POST['efLengthOfStay'];
$field_otherInfo = $_POST['efOtherInfo'];

$mail_to = 'James_Burnside94@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Enquiry Applicant-'.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Date: '.$field_date."\n";
$body_message .= 'Duration: '.$field_duration."\n";
$body_message .= 'otherInfo: '.$field_otherInfo."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Enquiry Sent.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Enquiry form failed to send. \n Please try again, or send an email             to enquiry@cannes-rental-apartment.com');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

and here's the Html body:

```
<body>


<fieldset style="display:block; width:500px;">
    <form action="enquiry.php" method="post">
    <table> 
                <tr> <td> <span class="enquiryFormHeader"> Enquiry Form     </span> <p>         </p></td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Name: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="efName"     id="efName"> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Email: </td> <td> <input type="text" name="efEmail"     id="efEmail"> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Phone or Moblie: </td> <td> <input type="text"     name="efPhone" id="efPhone"> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Intended travel date: </td> <td> <input type="text"     name="efTravelDate" id="efTravelDate"> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Intended length of stay: </td> <td> <input type="text"     name="efLengthOfStay" id="efLengthOfStay"> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td valign="top"> Any other information:  </td> <td> <textarea     name="efOtherInfo" id="efOtherInfo"> </textarea> <p> </p> </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td><input type="submit" value="Send Form"     class="submitButton"> </td> </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
    </fieldset>


</body>
```

If i do 
    $mail_status = mail($mail_to, 'subject', 'body_message', 'headers');

it sends a basic email perfectly.

On all occasions the Enquiry Sent alert appears.

Anyone know why it wont work??

Comment: Are there any errors? Do you actually get the JS alert() telling you 'enquiry failed to send'?

Comment: have you tried echoing the post data to make sure you are getting what you are expecting?  Also I believe that "inquiry" is the more common spelling although there is nothing wrong with enquiry

Comment: I'm new to php, this is the first website i've created, what exactly is echoing? and the enquiry sent always comes up :S

Comment: Suggestion: Use the [phpMailer class](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead; the plain old `mail()` function isn't really all that great.

Answer (score 1):

Run a `var_dump(get_defined_vars());` and ensure that they are set. Also check `/var/mail/user` where `user` is the PHP or Apache user, and see what errors are thrown at more of an OS level.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea how to :S do i insert var_dump(get_defined_vars()); into the php code?

Answer (score 0):

1- Exactly, what do you get? An empty mail or no mail at all?

2- Try to debug your $_POST, like user1593858 said. Right after the php opening tag add this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

and see if your fields are correct.

3- you say that if you do:

```
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, 'subject', 'body_message', 'headers');
```

it works; well try to substitute 'subject' with `$subject` or 'body_message' with `$body_message` until you isolate the problem.

Comment: I don't recieve an email at all :S

Doing the echo - all the variables are getting the correct values

and only $body_message works... the other two both arent working :S